# Why we need to extend ```ViewModel()``` for DataBinding and LiveData to create LiveData object

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

Without extending `ViewModel()` just with simple class I am able to implement LiveData and DataBinding example but I show in google developer doc to extend `ViewModel()` to create object of LiveData.So why we need to extend it?

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Comment: You don't have to, but ViewModel makes life a lot easier. ViewModel keeps your data alive when the device has configuration changes, like the screen rotating.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) for `ViewModel`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create a variable say `var a = 10` in `Fragment` or `Activity`, then you change it somewhere (ex: a button click), now it becomes `50`, then you rotate the screen (known as **Configuration Change)**, you will notice that `a` becomes `10` again. Sounds bothering sometimes huh? `ViewModel` is designed for solving this problem.

> Any variable you declare inside `ViewModel` will not be affected by **Configuration Change**.

Of course you must extend (inherit) your class from `ViewModel` or `AndroidViewModel` to gain this ability. But If you don't need this feature, you don't need to extend them.

---

Following shows the cases which will lead to configuration change:

1. Rotate screen
2. Change system language
3. Plug in physical keyboard
4. Connected to a mouse

**KEY POINT: After configuration change, Activity will be recreated, thus data might be lost.**